# Cant delete more than 200 contacts in HTC HERO

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I'm working on security application which will copy all contacts to some other database and delete all contacts from phonebook.
I'm testing this on android HTC HERO.
I'm successful to delete contacts from phonebook and create new contact info database,
Till 200 it is working, but after 200 contacts its not working properly.
After tht application starts throwing error.
There is one Sync with Google Option in Menu>Setting>Data Sync, I think that is creating problem.

There is notification that "Too many contacts deleted"
n if i click tht there will b a dialog with title "Delete Limit exceeded".
Is there anything i can do to stop syncronization or any other ideas by which i can achieve
required output?

Please Help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Google Sync is a bit picky - it hates it when there are too many things going on. The calendar has the same problem. I doubt that you want to turn syncing off (the user may not appreciate it either if you turn off a core functionality). What's your goal? Do you want the deletion of contacts to be synced with gmail.com or not?

At this point, your only options as far as I can tell would be to throttle your app so it doesn't delete more than 200 records within a certain timeframe. Alternatively, you could use gdata to modify the contacts, but that's a really roundabout way and probably not suitable for your needs.

Do you delete and then re-create the contacts? Is there any way for you to recycle existing contacts instead of deleting them and then starting from scratch?